# Which Skybox / HDRI formats does Ursina support?

Tags: ursina, hdrimages

I am attempting to build a custom Sky for Ursina. I created a few in the JPG and HDR format but both end up looking fish-eyed in the actual game. What formats are accepted by the Sky class?

Attempted both the HDR and cube methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Skybox examples on Ursina GitHub repo.

They are `jpg` images with `4096x1024` pixels resolution.

https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/blob/master/ursina/textures/sky_default.jpg

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pokepetter/ursina/master/ursina/textures/sky_default.jpg]

https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/blob/master/ursina/textures/sky_sunset.jpg

[image: https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/blob/master/ursina/textures/sky_sunset.jpg]